# Counting "good" strings of octal numbers of length $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My professor asked me to create a combinatorics problem. I have created one, i think it is a good problem, but I am having trouble solving it. Can anyone help me?

> A string of octal numbers of length $n$
> is called “good” if $k=n(0)+n(7)$ and $l=n(3)+n(4)$ are odd numbers, where $n(i)$, $i=0,1,\ldots,7$ represents the number of $i$’s found in the string. How many strings of octal numbers of length $n$ are “good”, where $n$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}$?

For example: 00334221, isn't a "good" octal string because $k=2$ is even number. But 007334221 is a "good" octal string, because $k=3$ and $l=3$ are both odd numbers.

We know that $a_1=0$, $a_2=8$, $a_3=96$, $a_4=896$. Where $a_n$ is the number of "good" octal string of length n.

I have tried in this method $a_n=4a_{n-1}+4b_{n-1}$. Where $b_n$ is string of octal numbers of length $n$ where $k$ is even and $l$ is odd (due to the symmetry of $k$ and $l$). But couldn't eliminate $b_n$.

Comment: This question was posted a few days ago. Are you sure that you created it yourself? If yes, then someone else agrees with you that it's a good question.

Comment: Try to create a problem that you *can* solve. If you must solve this problem, you need to show some effort. At the very least, count the good strings of length two and three.

Comment: @CalvinLin I reposted it to give more details because I'm new here and in response to feedback from some critics.

Comment: @DanielMathias We were asked to create good math problems. There wasn't a requirement for us to solve them. I have tried hard, but I couldn't solve it. I just wanted to know its solution, if i cant solve it.

Comment: [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4823257/edit) your question to show what you have tried. Include your count for strings of length two and three.

Comment: @DanielMathias Done!

Comment: If you have the first few numbers in the sequence, you can go check whether it’s extant on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). If not, neat! If it is, then the sequence you came up with has been of interest to others already.

Comment: @Semiclassical as I calculated a_4=896 (if didnt make any mistake). And i didnt find this serie in OEIS.

Comment: Perhaps you should include $c_n$, counting the number of strings with both k and l being even. Then you could use $a_n+2b_n+c_n=8^n$

Comment: $896$ is correct. The next five are $\{7680,63488,516096,4161536,33423360\}$. The sequence is not in OEIS.

Comment: Looking more closely, all of these terms are divisible by 8. Then starting from $n=0$ we have $$a_n/8 = 0, 1, 12, 112, 960, 7936, 960, 7936, 64512, 520192, 4177920,\ldots$$ This sequence _does_ appear on OEIS as [A016152](https://oeis.org/A016152). In particular, this yields $a_n=8\cdot 4^{n-1}(2^n-1)$. (This still leaves the question of _why_ $a_n/8$ is identical to this sequence.)

Comment: This sequence has closed form $a_n=\frac{8^n}{4}-\frac{4^n}{2}$ @Semiclassical

Comment: @DanielMathias Yes, you’re right: I missed that the OEIS sequence started at $n=0$ rather than $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to find the exponential generating function of the number of good strings.

With no restrictions on their numbers, the EGF of the number of strings of $0$s and $7$s is $e^x \cdot e^x=e^{2x}$; so the EGF of strings of an odd number of $0$s and $7$s is $(1/2)(e^{2x}-e^{-2x})$.  The same EGF counts the number of strings of $3$s and $4$s when the total number of $3$s and $4$s must be odd. So the EGF of the number of good strings is
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= (e^x)^4 \left( \frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2} \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{e^{8x} -2 e^{4x} +1}{4} 
\end{align}$$
The number of good strings of length $n$ is $n!$ times the coefficient of $x^n$ when $f(x)$ is expanded in a series, i.e.
$$n![x^n]f(x) = \frac{8^n - 2 \cdot 4^n}{4}$$
for $n \ge 1$.